# How to merge values from one serie to another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have two series, the first one is

```
Date     Item
2012  Cheeseburger
      Pasta
      Rice
2013  Tomatoes
      Salad
      Cheese
```

And the second one is :

```
Name  Cheese  Milk  Pasta  Juice  Rice  Cake  Tomatoes  Fries  Beef  Salad   Cheeseburger
2012    2      1     1.5     1    0.5    3      2.2      1.4    5      2       4.5
2013    1.7   0.9    1.7     1    0.75   3      2.2      1.3   5.3    1.9       4
```

I want to create a third column in the first serie to put the values present in the second one which fit with the same date and same name. I don't really knwo how to do it. 
I tried with the stack method but without success.

The final result should look like something like that :

```
Date     Item
2012  Cheeseburger  4.5
      Pasta         1.5
      Rice          0.5
2013  Tomatoes      2.2
      Salad         1.9
      Cheese        1.7
```

Does anyone know a way to do it ? Thanks

Here is the code that generates the second data frame

```py
df_two = pd.DataFrame({
     "2012": [2, 1, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 3, 2.2, 1.4, 5, 2, 4.5],
     "2013": [1.7, 0.9, 1.7, 1, 0.75, 3, 2.2, 1.3, 5.3, 1.9, 4]
})

df_two.columns = [
     "Cheese", "Milk", "Pasta", "Juice", "Rice",
     "Cake", "Tomatoes", "Fries", "Beef", "Salad", "Cheeseburger"]
```

Comment: According to your question, your output should have all the itmes from the second table. In other words, Cheese and Milk are always the first item in the output data frame? Or have you left them out intentially because you also want a filtering?

Comment: I also want a filtering and this is my principal issue. The first table is a selection from a "universe" that is globally represent in the second table

Comment: Oh, now I understand. This is actually quite easy. However, I still don't full understand your data structures. Are both `pandas` data frames?

Comment: Thank you for your help really. The first table is a Pandas Serie but the second table is a Pandas Data Frame

Comment: Cool! @wwnde did already provide a nice solution based on merging. Please mind my comment to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the first dataframe as `df`.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Take the second datframe as `df1` and `pd.melt` to collapse the columns to rows and come up with `df2`

```
df2=pd.melt(df1,id_vars=['Name'], value_vars=['Cheese', 'Milk', 'Pasta', 'Juice', 'Rice', 'Cake', 'Tomatoes',
       'Fries', 'Beef', 'Salad', 'Cheeseburger'],var_name='Item')
df2.columns=['Date','Item','value']#Rename columns
```

Left merge `df1` on `df2`

```
pd.merge(df,df2, how='left', on=['Date', 'Item']).set_index(['Date','Item'])
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! However, you would need [`series_one.to_frame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) as the first line. The first data structure is a series, not a `df`.

Comment: There is no need for my answer. Your answer is plane and simple. And it already got accepted, as it should.

Comment: It worked perfectly with your solution and as @MacOS said I needed to change it to a dataframe first but everything run well now. Thank you so much guys

Comment: Thanks @Kben59. Made a wild guess someone who knows a pd. series would know how to get a pd.dataframe from it. Apologies if the assumption caused harm. Kudos for working it out.